# Creating javascript object from array values

Tags: javascript, json

I am attempting to create a javascript object so that I can tranfsorm it into a json string in order to update a mysql table via php. I'm new to objects and json in javascript and so I have followed a couple of tutorials on the web but still can't seem to be getting this to work:

```
var idArray =      [ 1, 2, 3];
var slideNo =      [ 1, 2, 3];
var isPublished =  [ 0, 1, 0];
var floaText =     [ 1, 0 , 1];

var myObject = [];

for(var i = 0; i < idArray.length; i++) {
    myObject[i] = {
        slideId : idArray[i],
        slideNo : slideNo [i],
        isPublished : isPublished [i],
        floatText : floaText [i]
    };
}

alert(myObject[0].slideId);
```

I can't seem to get the above code work. I also tried to add quoation makrs like this:

```
myObject[i] = {
    slideId : "\"" + idArray[i] + "\"",
    slideNo : "\"" + slideNo[i] + "\"",
    isPublish : "\"" + isPublished[i] + "\"",
    floatText : "\"" + floaText[i]
};
```

But that doesn't seem to work either. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: sorry, I did actually have them as [] and not {} for the arrays

Comment: Based on your example slideArray, publishArray and floatArray don't exist. You have them named slideNo, isPublished, and floaText.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like your recent edit fixed one of the issues: you need `[]` around your arrays, not `{}`.

Next, you need to change your array variable names to match what you're using in your for loop.

Finally, myObject should probably be an array, not an object, so change its `{}` to `[]`.

Here's an updated version of your code:

```
var idArray =         [ 1, 2, 3];
var slideArray =      [ 1, 2, 3];
var publishArray =    [ 0, 1, 0];
var floatArray =      [ 1, 0 , 1];

var myObject = [];

for(var i = 0; i < idArray.length; i++) {
    myObject[i] = {
        slideId : idArray[i],
        slideNo : slideArray[i],
        isPublished : publishArray[i],
        floatText : floatArray[i]
    };
}

alert(myObject[0].slideId);
```

Comment: Thanks, I made those changes (see above code) but it still seems to be failing. In fact, not even the alert box is appearing. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Anything that's keeping your alert box from appearing is outside of the code you've posted so far.

Answer (score 0):

use JSON.stringify to convert object to json string

```
alert(JSON.stringify(myObject[i]));
```