# Create a JavaScript Array using value from JavaScript Objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I'm newbie to JavaScript, I have a JavaScript object

```
[{G4S: "31"},{G4S: "23"},{G4S: "31"},{G4S: "49"},{G4S: "110"},{G4S: "115"},{G4S: "104"}]
```

I want to create an array like

```
[31, 23, 31, 49, 110, 115, 104]
```

I referred some links, but they are showing how to create object from array, not array from object.
[How to get the key value in JSON object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8711580/how-to-get-the-key-value-in-json-object)

[Creating javascript object from array values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23399311/creating-javascript-object-from-array-values)

[Creating a JavaScript Object from two arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39127989/creating-a-javascript-object-from-two-arrays)

**I tried like this:**

```
for (var i = 0; i < chartDataG4S.length; i++) {
        var data = chartDataG4S[i]['G4S'];
        console.log(data);
      }
```

But it wont create an array. I'm stuck with this, any kind of help is welcome, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.map` to extract the `G4S` property in each object, and cast to a number, creating a new array in the process:

```js
const input = [{G4S: "31"},{G4S: "23"},{G4S: "31"},{G4S: "49"},{G4S: "110"},{G4S: "115"},{G4S: "104"}];
const output = input.map(({ G4S }) => Number(G4S));
console.log(output);
```

Or, the `for` loop version, if you prefer:

```js
const input = [{G4S: "31"},{G4S: "23"},{G4S: "31"},{G4S: "49"},{G4S: "110"},{G4S: "115"},{G4S: "104"}];
const output = [];
for (let i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
  output.push(Number(input[i].G4S));
}
console.log(output);
```

Comment: Great, thanks buddy it's working fine. Just quick question, why we use const rather than var?

Comment: `var` has problems that can trip you up - for example, it has unintuitive function scope, rather than block scope, and gets hoisted. `const` does not have either of those issues, and as another plus, when you see `const`, you *know* that the following variable will never be reassigned, which makes reading and understanding code at a glance easier. Best to use `const` whenever you can, use `let` when you can't (which doesn't have `var`'s problems, but is reasignable), and never use `var`. (Transpile to ES5 during your build process to support ancient browsers)

Answer (score 4):

You can simply use `.map()`:

```js
let data = [{G4S: "31"},{G4S: "23"},{G4S: "31"},{G4S: "49"},{G4S: "110"},{G4S: "115"},{G4S: "104"}];

let result = data.map(({ G4S }) => Number(G4S));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
let chartDataG4S = [{G4S: "31"},{G4S: "23"},{G4S: "31"},{G4S: "49"},{G4S: "110"},{G4S: "115"},{G4S: "104"}];

let result = chartDataG4S.map(o => Number(o.G4S));
console.log(result);
```

The function map() which originates from functional programming and is inherent in JavaScript's arrays, facilitates accessing the value of each object's  G4S property, namely a numeric string.  The function Number() takes each string value and converts it to a number. That return value is then added to a new result array.

While Array object's map() is convenient to use, note you may also achieve the same results with explicit iteration as follows:

```js
let chartDataG4S = [{G4S: "31"},{G4S: "23"},{G4S: "31"},{G4S: "49"},{G4S: "110"},{G4S: "115"},{G4S: "104"}]

let result = [];

for (var i=0; i in chartDataG4S; i++) {
  result.push(Number(chartDataG4S[i].G4S));
}


console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var newArray = [];  // New array declaration to be used to push the values.
var objArray = [{G4S: "31"},{G4S: "23"},{G4S: "31"},{G4S: "49"},{G4S: "110"},{G4S: "115"},{G4S: "104"}];  // Your array of objects

objArray.forEach(function(elem){
    newArray.push(elem.G4S);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in simple steps , get arrays of all values of object using `map` and merge all into single one here is how.

```js
let data = [{G4S: "31"},{G4S: "23"},{G4S: "31"},{G4S:"49"},{G4S: "110"},{G4S: "115"},{G4S: "104"}];

//step 1
let arr = data.map(da => Object.values(da)); // irrespective of keys
//step 2 
let result = arr.reduce((acc, val) => acc.concat(val), []);
console.log(result);
// in one liner.
console.log(data.map(da => Object.values(da)).reduce((acc, val) => acc.concat(val), []))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is basically an array and you can do like this.

```
let arr = [{G4S: "31"},{G4S: "23"},{G4S: "31"},{G4S: "49"},{G4S: "110"},{G4S: "115"},{G4S: "104"}];
let arr1 =[];
for(let i=0; i<are.length; i++)
    arr1.push(are[i].G4S);
```

Comment: So you just need to use data.push instead of data = something in your code.

Comment: And initialize data array outside the loop